# Stream radio and get stream title from Ubuntu server

Tags: server, sound, streaming, internet-radio

How can I stream Internet radio from my server? Actually, I don't want to stream and listen to it, just to get stream titles? For example, I have 7 radios, I want to get stream titles from all radios as quick as possible.

Is it possible to do that?

Right now I am getting stream titles with PHP (fsockopen), but it is slow, so I need something faster.

Comment: Are you running the streaming server for those yourself? What is it? Icecast?

Comment: No, I want to play other servers, mostly icecast servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if those are Icecast 2.4 or newer, then you can just access their JSON API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26924141/2648865

Some other options are listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26817214/2648865